# extension methods in golang?

Tags: .net, go

I am a .NET guy. Very much new to the Go language.

In .NET we have extension methods. Is there anything equivalent in Go?

In .NET I will do like `bsonTrans["trans.ticket"]`

in that bsonTrans => bson document

```
    "trans.ticket" => key in json

     trans is outer level and

     ticket is inner level
```

I am using native mongodb driver. In that I add my extension functions to perform these operations.

Like wise up to the nth level I did it .NET.

I would like to apply the same logic in Go.

**Example**

```
 b := []byte(trans)
var config map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &config)

fmt.Println(config["data"].(map[string] interface{})["issued"])
```

For instance in that example, can i do something like:

**config["data.issued"]** which should give the value in return ?

Please help me in figuring this out...

**Actual json :-**

(The actual json is too big, however I am providing a sample of it with less fields.)

```
{
 "_id" : 2001,
    "address" : {
        "line1" : "",
        "line2" : "",
        "line3" : ""
       },
    "tickets" : [ 
        {
            "seq" : 2,
            "add" : [
              {
              "seq" : "",
              "amnt" : 50
              },

              {
              "seq" : "",
              "amnt" : 50
              {
              "seq" : "",
              "amnt" : 50
              }
              }

              }
             ]
}
```

**Reason for not using struct** is my json has too many nested structures and I have more than 10 schemas with different structures.

So I left out structs.

I admit that I am not sure that omitting structs is the best way.

Comment: can you post an actual sample of your json?  With that I can show you how it works.  Also, is there a reason you don't want to use a formal struct to marshal the data instead of the generic map[string]interface{}?  While the later will work, I tend to favor an actual well defined struct to marshal into.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Extension methods are not supported the way it is in .NET.

The closest thing you can do is create a type from string and create a method on that type:

```
type MyString string
func (m *MyString) Method() {
}

func main() {
    var s MyString = ""
    s.Method()
}
```

Comment: Regarding the "type MyString string"...is there a way to convert a string to a MyString without some helper function attached or otherwise to MyString? Will Interface{} even do it, or will something at run-time throw an error in reflection?

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2017:**

**Go does support extension methods for [receiver types](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4).**

Based on type assertions in Go 1.9, you can simply add = where you define the type, then add methods to it.

```
type NewStruct = OldStrut
func (m *NewStruct) ExtensionMethod() {
}
```

To call it:

```
func main() {
    s := OldStruct{}
    s.ExtensionMethod()
}
```

Comment: When I try that I get this compile error: `cannot define new methods on non-local type`

Comment: The fix is to remove the equals sign so the corrected line reads `type NewStruct OldStrut`

Comment: @HairOfTheDog: As Iv'e written in the answer the `=` works with receiver types only.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog : Mohsen's example works for me with Go 1.16. If I change it to `type NewStruct OldStruct` then I had to do type conversion `ns := NewStruct(s)` which is a copy of OldStruct and not an extension method.

Comment: I have not learned Go yet. What is the difference between a "receiver type" and a "non-receiver type"? (the link did not seem to answer that)

Comment: @Venryx: The difference between *receiver types* and value types in Go is somewhat like the difference between *reference types* and value types in Dotnet. In this specific answer it means that you cannot do the following: `struct MyCustomString = string`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of code that uses your json.  Your json sample wasn't valid, so I corrected it to what I think your intent was.

I think you will find using a map[string]interface{} with a deeply nested struct will not work out, but I don't know your use case, so I can't say for sure.

Here is an interactive link that runs the code as well: http://play.golang.org/p/0gtYMfBMWX

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

func main() {
  b := []byte(`{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "add": [
        {
          "amnt": 50,
          "seq": ""
        },
        {
          "amnt": 50,
          "seq": ""
        },
        {
          "amnt": 50,
          "seq": ""
        }
      ],
      "seq": 2
    }
  ],
  "address": {
    "line3": "",
    "line2": "",
    "line1": ""
  },
  "_id": 2001
}`)
  var config map[string]interface{}
  if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &config); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    return
  }

  // I'm not sure what part of the data you are trying to get at here...
  //fmt.Println(config["data"].(map[string]interface{})["issued"])

  fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", config)

  tickets := config["tickets"]
  fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", tickets)

}
```